# Object allocation in PermGen

Tags: java, permgen

I have a problem about an excessive memory allocation in PermGen.

I write a small code to monitoring size of this memory space and I noticed that after almost each method execution the size of allocated memory grows. Maybe there are a lot of global object in my application? Is there a way to know which object are allocated in PermGen? Currently I only know the size of used memory.

This is the code that I write, defined as advice executed after each method invocation:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.MemoryPoolMXBean;


@Aspect
public class PermGenStat {

    static Long bytesPrecedenti = getUsedPermGenBytes();

    private static Long getUsedPermGenBytes() {

    Long bytes = 0L;

    Iterator<MemoryPoolMXBean> iter = ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans().iterator();

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            MemoryPoolMXBean item = (MemoryPoolMXBean) iter.next();
            if (item.getName().equals("PS Perm Gen"))
                bytes = item.getUsage().getUsed();
        }

        return bytes;
    }

    @AfterReturning (pointcut = "execution(* it.xxx.yyy.*.*.*.*(..))",
                     returning = "result")

    public void afterReturning (JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {

        if (joinPoint != null &&
        joinPoint.getTarget() != null &&
        joinPoint.getTarget().getClass() != null &&
        joinPoint.getSignature() != null &&
        joinPoint.getSignature().getName() != null) {

        try {
            Long bytes = getUsedPermGenBytes();
            Long diff = bytes - bytesPrecedenti;

            if (diff >= 1) {    
                System.out.println("Metodo: " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().toString().substring(6) + "." +                                                    joinPoint.getSignature().getName().toString());

               System.out.println("PermGen (KB): " + Math.round((double)bytesPrecedenti / 1024) + " -> " +
                                                      Math.round((double)bytes / 1024) +
                                               " [" + Math.round((double)diff / 1024) + "]");
            }
            bytesPrecedenti = bytes;
    }
            catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("******************** Eccezione ********************");
                System.out.println("Classe: PermGenStat - Metodo: afterReturning");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Objects are only on the heap (or perhaps the stack) It is code which uses the perm gen in Java 7.

Comment: in PermGen space, there are normally only ClassLoaders and Class objects. Once a class is used the first time, it should be loaded in PermGen and not increase the PermGen anymore.

The garbage collector algorithms are implementation specific, and AFAIK, there is no generic API to adress them. All you can do is do a heap dump, and if you suspect a leak, compare successive heapdumps. If you suspect a leak in PermGen, look in the heap dump for nr. of loaded classes, and see what's happening there.

Answer (score 4):

The PermGen space mostly contains reflection data. Objects that are created at runtime are normally stored on the heap, so creating them should not increase the size of the PermGen space.

However (this is just a guess), if you use runtime weaving or call methods that haven't been called before (which might need classes that have not been loaded yet) the JVM might load additional reflection data into the PermGen space (methods, classes, proxy classes created by the weaving process etc.). That might be the reason you experience that increase in PermGen space usage.

Comment: The size of PermGen is increased also if execute the same methods many times, although during the first execution the allocated memory is more. I my project I use spring framework that uses a reflection, maybe is it that allocate a lot of memory in PermGen.

Comment: @user2572547 that might be the case. You could use jconsole to check the number of loaded classes.